# Is there a way to fully deploy Google Actions from command line?

Tags: actions-on-google

When building Google Actions using the Actions SDK to run on the Assistant or Google Home, according to https://developers.google.com/actions/extending-the-assistant you can use the firebase and gactions command line tools to partially automate deployment.

However it seems that the final steps of providing the app information and submitting it for review, as well as actually setting up the project in the first place, can only be done using the Actions on Google Console web interface (https://console.actions.google.com/).

This does not seem practical in a production environment where it would be more convenient to integrate all steps into an automated workflow, ideally by using command line tools (or another solution that does not require interaction with a GUI, such as a REST API) for all steps. Is there a way of doing it for Google Actions?

Answer (score 0):

At the moment you can't submit your app for review from the command line.

The steps you mentioned (app info etc') needs to be completed in the actions console.